# How can I create a SafeFrame (like the one created by Google Ad Manager)?

Tags: web, iframe, google-ad-manager

Google Ad Manager can render ads inside a SafeFrame, that is basically an iframe with everything blocked (you can't access `window.top` or `window.parent`, for instance; you can only use `window.postMessage()` for in-page communication). Also, SafeFrames usually expose an API via an object called `$sf` that allows a programmer to do things, like expand, or get info about the geometry.

So, my question is, **is there a way to create *by myself* a fully-fledged, standard (by any means) safeframe**? It may be useful for testing and/or to know how things work in safeframe environment.

Comment: it looks that this repo contains the answer, but it's not informative by any means. https://github.com/InteractiveAdvertisingBureau/safeframe/

Answer (score 0):

I share your problem. I'm still in the middle of figuring out the implementation of SafeFrame in order to create a preview tool.

I can only share my current findings:
Unfortunately, the official SafeFrame dev tools from IAB Tech Labs are not available anymore. Most resources point to a broken (non-secure ¯\*(ツ)*/¯) page: safeframes.net
I believe each developer needs to create a custom implementation in order to test and develop for SafeFrame.

Side note, I am curious about the adoption share of SafeFrame 2.0. Reason I'm curious, is that IAB Tech Lab has already dropped development on SafeFrame and shifted focus (with the same Working Group) on a new cross-platform specification called [SHARC](https://iabtechlab.com/blog/sharc-were-going-to-need-a-bigger-team/) which is meant to be a one solution for both app and web environments (Mraid + SafeFrame for the lack of a better explanation)

> Note: SafeFrame work has shifted to the new Safe HTML Ad Richmedia
> Container (SHARC), scheduled for release to public comment in early
> 2022. The SafeFrame working group has been dismantled and replaced by the Safe Ad Container working group.

SHARC sounds really good! A first draft already exists, but no dev tools yet to support ad developers.
Alas, given how recent it is and its current state, I'd say this needs a few more years until it has any real adoption from publishers and exchanges.